# Execution plan for functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

If I change user-defined function (UDF) that is in use in another UDF will the PostgreSQL rebuild execution plan for both of them or only for changed one?

Comment: Can't you try this out and just see what happens using `EXPLAIN` ?

Comment: Yeah, the question was more about cache, sorry for bad wording, I asked another question, please have a look here: [Execution plan cache for PL/pgSQL functions in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698386/execution-plan-cache-for-pl-pgsql-functions-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

If a function is unchanged, the execution plans for all its queries should remain cached.

So only the execution plans for the function you changed will be recalculated.

You can use the SQL statement `DISCARD PLANS` to discard all cached plans.

Comment: Would it depend on [Inlining_of_SQL_functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions)?

Comment: Plans are not cached for SQL functions, only for PL/pgSQL functions.

Comment: Is it something that specified in LANGUAGE clause?

Comment: Right. Functions can be written in a number of languages in PostgreSQL, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang.html). Only PL/pgSQL caches plans.