# Execution plan cache for PL/pgSQL functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, caching, sql-execution-plan

If I change PL/pgSQL function that is in use in another PL/pgSQL function will the PostgreSQL rebuild execution plan for both of them or only for changed one?

Say I have 2 functions using third one. Say function `check_permission(user_id)` is used by `get_company(user_id)` and `get_location(user_id)`.

And I they got cached their execution plan somehow.

And then I change `check_permission`, would the execution plan caches for `get_company(user_id)` and `get_location(user_id)` be deleted and rebuilt on demand?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659067/execution-plan-for-functions-in-postgresql) is not a duplicate of the current question because one question is about execution plan cache, the other is  just about execution plan with no cache mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL tracks dependencies, and it flushes caches pretty aggressively when things change.

If you change a function, it'll invalidate at least the plans of all functions that depend on it. In practice, IIRC it just flushes all cached query plans entirely.

The same is true of views that depend on other views, prepared statements that reference views, etc.

If you find a case where it fails to do so you have found a bug. Please report it with a complete reproducible test case.

Comment: IMHO views are not caching their execution plans.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Not by themselves, but prepared statements that use views cache the plan, including any inlined or subplan views

Comment: Functions have no dependencies on functions they call; check `pg_depend`. So PostgreSQL has no idea which functions depend on which others.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe why did not you post it as an answer?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, What should I do now, they are both mine questions and they have different answers. I tried to delete the other one where cache was not mentioned, but I cannot since this one is marked as a duplicate for it.

Comment: I can rephrase the other question to make it look like this one, will it do?

Comment: It's fine, just ignore.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ... which is why we flush the whole plancache.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood. The answer that PostgreSQL flushes all plans is fine. The downvote was just because it suggested that PostgreSQL tracks dependencies between functions. I'll try to revert the downvote as soon as I can.

Comment: you can drop function and cascade dependencies as it is stated in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-dropfunction.html). It means that dependancies are tracked by postgreSQL. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Sure, dependencies *are* tracked in PostgreSQL, just no dependencies between functions. For example, a view could depend on a function.